# background-clip: content box: clip to specific backgrond-color

Tags: css

Is it possible to change the space between a rectangle and its border from transparent to white by using CSS only (and not changing HTML)?

```css
body {
  background: beige;
}

div {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid red;

  padding: 5px;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need at least two layers to do this

```css
body {
  background: beige;
}

.box {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(grey 0 0) content-box,
   white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Or consider box-shaow and keep the border white

```css
body {
  background: beige;
}

.box {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  background: grey;
  border:5px solid white;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px  red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible but you can use a gradient and background-color to achieve this.

```css
body {
  background: lightyellow;
}

.a {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  --p: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(gray, gray) 50% 50% / calc(100% - var(--p) * 2) calc(100% - var(--p) * 2) no-repeat;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```